# Lack of printer drivers

Tags: drivers, printing

just tried out Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit.   Cannot find printer drivers for my Epson 2500ET or my Kyocera FS3800 laser.   I do not seem to be able to connect to the Epson via wifi either.  Both printers are found on my network, but it would appear that there are no Linux drivers for either. any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both manufacturers have made Linux drivers available for those models. I found them just by searching for the model and "linux driver" and following the links that came up.

Search for ET-2500 on http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX and you'll find Linux drivers available for download.

Kyocera has PPD files available at http://usa.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com/americas/jsp/Kyocera/download_center.jsp (choose "Legacy Products | Printers" and then FS-3800.)

If you have trouble installing or using them, feel free to ask for more specific help in a new question on this site.